# Regexp to read HTML and match onlu specific word in text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this String:

```
<body>
    <span class="open crack-opener o_open i_opens ng-open" style='open'>Open opens openes "Open opens openes" clopened</span>
</body>
```

I need to select only the words OPEN or OPENS or OPENES only inside the text. I tried the following RegExp, but it only selects the tags. I need to negate this and select the words.

```
/(<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)?>)/ig
```

How do I negate this match and insert the word open?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be considerably easier to use jQuery for this. Regex can ***never*** be a proper HTML parser. With jQuery, it would be as simple as `$('<body><span class="open crack-opener o_open i_opens ng-open" style="open">Open opens openes "Open opens openes" clopened</span></body>',".open").text()`

Comment: But actually it is meant to read the whole body tag and highlight dynamic words, not only a specific word, neither exactly inside the .open tag. So maybe if run through all text() inside all tags it would too heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with: Do not use regex to parse HTML, it is not a good idea, since it is impossible to build regex parsing HTML :)

But back to your question:

```
var str="<body><span class=\"open crack-opener o_open i_opens ng-open\" style='open'>Open opens openes \"Open opens openes\" clopened</span></body>";
var words=str.match(/(\bopen\b|\bopens\b|\bopenes\b)(?=[^>]*<)/ig);
```

This will search for your words followed by anything except for `>` and then followed by `<`. That solution is not the best but you cannot expect regex to do something it was not designed for.